# How to achieve Automatic Rollback in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, rollback

Let's say I've a deployment. For some reason it's not responding after sometime. Is there any way to tell Kubernetes to rollback to previous version automatically on failure?

Comment: If your readiness probes are set up correctly, most of the old pods will still be running until the new ones report as healthy.  There's nothing in Kubernetes to automatically roll back, but it knows to not upgrade to broken versions, if you can tell it how to detect "broken".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mentioned that:

> I've a deployment. For some reason it's not responding after sometime.

In this case, you can use [liveness and readiness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) probes:

> The kubelet uses liveness probes to know when to restart a container. For example, liveness probes could catch a deadlock, where an application is running, but unable to make progress. Restarting a container in such a state can help to make the application more available despite bugs.

> The kubelet uses readiness probes to know when a container is ready to start accepting traffic. A Pod is considered ready when all of its containers are ready. One use of this signal is to control which Pods are used as backends for Services. When a Pod is not ready, it is removed from Service load balancers.

The above probes may prevent you from deploying a corrupted version, however liveness and readiness probes aren't able to rollback your Deployment to the previous version. There was a similar [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23211) on Github, but I am not sure there will be any progress on this matter in the near future.

If you really want to automate the rollback process, below I will describe a solution that you may find helpful.

---

This solution requires running `kubectl` commands from within the Pod.
In short, you can use a script to continuously monitor your Deployments, and when errors occur you can run `kubectl rollout undo deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME`.

First, you need to decide how to find failed Deployments. As an example, I'll check Deployments that perform the update for more than 10s with the following command:
**NOTE:** You can use a different command depending on your need.

```
kubectl rollout status deployment ${deployment} --timeout=10s
```

To constantly monitor all Deployments in the `default` Namespace, we can create a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    sleep 60
    deployments=$(kubectl get deployments --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep -v "deployment-checker")
    echo "====== $(date) ======"
    for deployment in ${deployments}; do
        if ! kubectl rollout status deployment ${deployment} --timeout=10s 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
            echo "Error: ${deployment} - rolling back!"
            kubectl rollout undo deployment ${deployment}
        else
            echo "Ok: ${deployment}"
        fi
    done
done
```

We want to run this script from inside the Pod, so I converted it to `ConfigMap` which will allow us to mount this script in a volume (see: [Using ConfigMaps as files from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#using-configmaps-as-files-from-a-pod)):

```
$ cat check-script-configmap.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: check-script
data:
  checkScript.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash

    while true; do
        sleep 60
        deployments=$(kubectl get deployments --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep -v "deployment-checker")
        echo "====== $(date) ======"
        for deployment in ${deployments}; do
            if ! kubectl rollout status deployment ${deployment} --timeout=10s 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
                echo "Error: ${deployment} - rolling back!"
                kubectl rollout undo deployment ${deployment}
            else
                echo "Ok: ${deployment}"
            fi
        done
    done        

$ kubectl apply -f check-script-configmap.yml
configmap/check-script created
```

I've created a separate `deployment-checker` ServiceAccount with the `edit` Role assigned and our Pod will run under this ServiceAccount:
**NOTE:** I've created a Deployment instead of a single Pod.

```
$ cat all-in-one.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: deployment-checker
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: deployment-checker-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: deployment-checker
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: deployment-checker
  name: deployment-checker
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deployment-checker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deployment-checker
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: deployment-checker
      volumes:
        - name: check-script
          configMap:
            name: check-script
      containers:
      - image: bitnami/kubectl
        name: test
        command: ["bash", "/mnt/checkScript.sh"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: check-script
          mountPath: /mnt
```

After applying the above manifest, the `deployment-checker` Deployment was created and started monitoring Deployment resources in the `default` Namespace:

```
$ kubectl apply -f all-in-one.yaml
serviceaccount/deployment-checker created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/deployment-checker-binding created
deployment.apps/deployment-checker created

$ kubectl get deploy,pod | grep "deployment-checker"
deployment.apps/deployment-checker   1/1     1            
pod/deployment-checker-69c8896676-pqg9h   1/1     Running
```

Finally, we can check how it works. I've created three Deployments (`app-1`, `app-2`, `app-3`):

```
$ kubectl create deploy app-1 --image=nginx
deployment.apps/app-1 created

$ kubectl create deploy app-2 --image=nginx
deployment.apps/app-2 created

$ kubectl create deploy app-3 --image=nginx
deployment.apps/app-3 created
```

Then I changed the image for the `app-1` to the incorrect one (`nnnginx`):

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/app-1 nginx=nnnginx
deployment.apps/app-1 image updated
```

In the `deployment-checker` logs we can see that the `app-1` has been rolled back to the previous version:

```
$ kubectl logs -f  deployment-checker-69c8896676-pqg9h
...
====== Thu Oct  7 09:20:15 UTC 2021 ======
Ok: app-1
Ok: app-2
Ok: app-3
====== Thu Oct  7 09:21:16 UTC 2021 ======
Error: app-1 - rolling back!
deployment.apps/app-1 rolled back
Ok: app-2
Ok: app-3
```

Comment: Amazing idea, thanks a million!

Comment: Thank you so much for this ! I would like to use different values of timeout for some deployments. I'm very bad at bash, can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon Argo Rollout which addresses this non automatic rollback and many other deployment related things.

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/